# Linq latter processing behavior

Tags: .net, database, linq, orm, late-binding

In this situation:

```
var allCustomers = from c in customers select c;
var oldCustomers = from o in allCustomers where o.age > 70 select o;
```

Will **where** clause reach database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you mean:

```
var oldCustomers = from o in allCustomers where o.age > 70 select o;
```

And Yes, it will reach the database.

Try using LINQPad to see the SQL code generated. Here's an example:

I have a `Actor` table that has the fields:

`Id | Name | Age`

The code:

```
var x = from c in Actors where c.Name.Contains("a") select c;
var y = from c in x where c.Age > 0 select c;
```

gets translated to:

```
-- Region Parameters
DECLARE @p0 Int = 0
DECLARE @p1 NVarChar(3) = '%a%'
-- EndRegion
SELECT [t0].[Id], [t0].[Name], [t0].[Age]
FROM [Actor] AS [t0]
WHERE ([t0].[Age] > @p0) AND ([t0].[Name] LIKE @p1)
```

so you can see how it mixes the two queries in only one.

Remember, IEnumerables are lazy, so you unless their elements have to be known (because you iterate through them, or because you do `.Count()` to see how many items are, etc), it won't perform any query/operation.

Comment: So 
var allCustomers = from c in customers select c; 
didn't reach database yet?

Comment: @Eduardo No, it didn't. It will reach the database when it has to. In my example, neither `x` nor `y` will reach the database, but when you iterate through the elements of `y` or something, it will perform the query. That's what I did to see the SQL it generates.

Comment: correct.  not until you actually iterate over allCustomers will the database be queried

Comment: @Eduardo That's why you don't have to do your LINQ to SQL queries in only one statement :)

Comment: So I see an issue: a 3 tier application that returns IEnumerable or IQueryable from data access logic is a fake 3 tier application as database queries are hidden and spread throughout all tiers. That makes it too difficult to find and correct performance bugs related to database.

Comment: @Eduardo If you want to avoid this in your example, you still have the option of doing: `var allCustomers = (from c in customers select c).AsEnumerable();`